# slides.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have HTML which includes scripts in following order

```
<script src="../static/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../static/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../static/js/slides.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../static/js/app.js" type="text/javascript">
```

and images are tied to div as

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slides">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/01.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/02.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/03.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/04.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/05.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/06.JPG">
    </div>
</div>
```

where `jquery.js` is JQuery v1.7.2 and `slide.js` is latest slide.js downloaded.

To me it seems correct order as well. What my `app.js` does is

```
$(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        width: 600,
        height: 120,
        pagination: false,
        previous: false
    });
    $('#slides').slides("play");
});
```

I tried on both Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't seem to work, all my images are displayed one after the another

What is that I am not doing right here??

Comment: It doesn't seem to work _how_? No slideshow? slideshow but it doesn't do anything? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't see any errors in console @Basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget some div classes.

You can find a jsfiddle example I put in place here : http://jsfiddle.net/rNF8G/

EDIT 1:

You can add the `play: 2000` property to the first block instead of calling it like this : `$('#slides').slides("play");` 
See my edit here : http://jsfiddle.net/rNF8G/1/

EDIT 2:

To remove pagination, all you have to do is to add the following property :

`generatePagination: false`

You can see it in the following update : http://jsfiddle.net/rNF8G/117/

Comment: Thank you @Zakaria, this works perfectly well, the only thing is I want to see dots rather numbers for the number of slides I have, trying to figure that out

Comment: @PriestVallon The problem is that the slides JS library wasn't reachable anymore. I updated the latest link : http://jsfiddle.net/rNF8G/117/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this...

```
$(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        width: 600,
        height: 120,
        pagination: false,
        previous: false
    });
    $('#slides').slides("play");
});
```

try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        width: 600,
        height: 120,
        pagination: false,
        previous: false
    });
    $('#slides').slides("play");
});
```

You don't seem to be attaching the handler correctly to the document ready event

If that doesn't work, can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: no luck, all I see warnings realted to bootstrap.css but no error/warning related to this.

Comment: never tied jsfiddle, tell me what info you need and i'll give that on jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle is just place where you can paste html, javascript, etc... and it gives a working example - very handy for sharing the problem with others - so paste your html/javascript/etc... and recreate the problem. On the bright side, getting error messages is a good thing - this is definitely the right way to attach the event so now you need to track down why you're getting errors. What are they?

Comment: Thanks daydreamer but I think @Zakaria beat us to it

Answer (score 0):

Try with JQuery Cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

**HTML**

```
<div id="slides">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/01.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/02.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/03.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/04.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/05.JPG">
        <img src="../static/img/slideshow/06.JPG">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#slides').cycle({ 
        fx:     'scrollRight', 
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 5000
});
```

Comment: Note that calling cycle directly like this, not through the `document.ready` event will fail if the div is declared after the javascript (as the JS will run before it's been parsed). You should always put initialisation code in `$(document).ready(function(){/*here*/})` . That said, I'm not familiar with cycle and it may be a better solution - jsut move the example JS into the ready event